# Google Analytics custom event tracking on android apps

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm trying to get info about specific button clicks inside my app.
What I've done so far (using one of the guides I've found on the web) is :

```
Tracker tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker(ID);

HashMap<String, String> hitParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
hitParameters.put(Fields.EVENT_CATEGORY, "UI Action");
hitParameters.put(Fields.EVENT_ACTION, "Button Pressed");
hitParameters.put(Fields.EVENT_LABEL, "play");

tracker.send(hitParameters);
```

I'm not getting any reaction to this code at the google analytic website.
Is there something wrong with the code?

Notice:
* The real time analytics and overview is working great in general, except those events.

Comment: See duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21833193/435605

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I\ve done this the following way (using easytracker & v3 version of analytics):

```
EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this);
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder
    .createEvent(
        "UI Action", // Event category (required)
        "Button Pressed", // Event action (required)
        "play", // Event label
         null) // Event value
    .build()
 );
```

Also see [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/events)

Other than that, please note that events can take a while to show up on the analytics page in my experience.

Comment: This answer works very well. Cannot accept it due to reputation. Thanks alot!

Comment: @user1697840 hi, for how long you've waited for the results to show up? thanks.

Comment: This answer's code looks the same as the question's code. What difference does it make if you create and populate the map yourself or have a builder to populate it for you? How I would love to get a hold of the source code...

Comment: I think that it will show up very quickly if you set the `ga_dispatchPeriod` value in `analytics.xml` to a low value.

Comment: @LeiLeyba According to the [manual](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/events), `value` is not a required value.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the HIT_TYPE param. See in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/advanced) for more info. You can also use MapBuilder. MapBuilder will set the HIT_TYPE for you.

Example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21833193/435605):

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(Fields.HIT_TYPE, com.google.analytics.tracking.android.HitTypes.EVENT);
map.put(Fields.EVENT_CATEGORY, "UI Action");
map.put(Fields.EVENT_ACTION, "Button Pressed");
tracker.send(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            com.google.analytics.tracking.android.Tracker tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(YOUR_Activity.this).getTracker("YOUR_ID);
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(Fields.HIT_TYPE, com.google.analytics.tracking.android.HitTypes.EVENT);
            map.put(Fields.EVENT_CATEGORY, "Home page");
            map.put(Fields.EVENT_ACTION, "Trophy");
            tracker.send(map);
```